# Inserir Loop em C

Tags: c, c++, loop, while

desejo inserir uma opção de o usuário digitar quantas rodadas ele quer jogar contra a cpu nesse jogo de joquenpo segue meu código abaixo, será que algum mestre do c pode me ajudar ? agradeço

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int pontos_jogador=0, pontos_cpu=0;
main()
{
    jokenpo();
}
int jokenpo()
{
    int jogador, cpu;
    printf ("---JokenPo---\n");
    printf ("%d Jogador X CPU %d\n", pontos_jogador, pontos_cpu);
    printf ("-------------\n");
    printf ("0. Pedra\n");
    printf ("1. Papel\n");
    printf ("2. Tesoura\n");
    printf ("3. Sair\n\n");
    
      printf ("Escolha sua opcao ");
    scanf ("%d", &jogador);
    if (jogador < 0 || jogador >=3)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    srand(time(NULL));
    cpu = rand() % 3; //cpu escolhe um numero aleatorio de 0 até 2
    switch(cpu)
    {
        case 0: printf (" \n CPU escolheu Pedra\n"); break;
        case 1: printf (" \n CPU escolheu Papel\n"); break;
        case 2: printf (" \n CPU escolheu Tesoura\n"); break;
    }
    if ((jogador == 0 && cpu==2) || (jogador == 1 && cpu == 0) || (jogador == 2 && cpu == 1)) // aqui vejo quem foi o vencedor
        {
            printf("\n Voce venceu!\n");
            pontos_jogador++;
            jokenpo();
        }
    if (jogador == cpu) // aqui vejo se teve empate
        {
            printf ("\n o jogo Empatou!\n");
            jokenpo();
        }
    else
        {
            printf ("\n CPU venceu!\n");
            pontos_cpu++;
            jokenpo();

        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não vejo a menor necessidade de você utilizar uma função recursiva para o que deseja.

Answer (score 0):

##Boa tarde amigo, criei uma variavel int chamada "vezes" e um for no int main que ira rodar o numero digitado e armazenado nessa variavel (vezes) assim sua função  jokenpo(); ira rodar o numero de vezes armazenado na variavel (vezes).

##Dica: Preste um pouco de atenção na indentação do código para facilitar o entendimento do amigo programador, kkkkkkk é nois

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>

//Variaveis Globais
int pontos_jogador=0, pontos_cpu=0;

int jokenpo()
{
int jogador, cpu;
printf ("---JokenPo---\n");
printf ("%d Jogador X CPU %d\n", pontos_jogador, pontos_cpu);
printf ("-------------\n");
printf ("0. Pedra\n");
printf ("1. Papel\n");
printf ("2. Tesoura\n");
printf ("3. Sair\n\n");

printf ("Escolha sua opcao ");
scanf ("%d", &jogador);
if (jogador < 0 || jogador >=3)
{
    exit(0);
}
srand(time(NULL));
cpu = rand() % 3; //cpu escolhe um numero aleatorio de 0 até 2
switch(cpu)
case 0:
    printf (" \n CPU escolheu Pedra\n");
    break;
case 1:
    printf (" \n CPU escolheu Papel\n");
    break;
case 2:
    printf (" \n CPU escolheu Tesoura\n");
    break;
}
if ((jogador == 0 && cpu==2) || (jogador == 1 && cpu == 0) || (jogador == 2 && cpu == 1)) // aqui vejo quem foi o vencedor
{
    printf("\n Voce venceu!\n");
    pontos_jogador++;
}
if (jogador == cpu) // aqui vejo se teve empate
{
    printf ("\n o jogo Empatou!\n");
}
    else
{
    printf ("\n CPU venceu!\n");
    pontos_cpu++;

}
return 0;
}
int main()
{
    int contador; //variável de controle do loop
    int vezes;// variavel que irá guardar suas repetições

    printf("Digite o numero de vezes que vc gostaria de jogar: ");
    scanf("%d", &vezes);

    for(contador = 1; contador <= vezes; contador++)
    {
        jokenpo();
    }
    return(0);
}
```